# How to delete certain directory in linux

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have a huge directory that contain a lot of subdirectory. But some subdirectory's name are **number** or strange letter like **β** or some other strange things. 
The directory looks like this:

```
/
/a,/b,/1,/0,/$,/β
/a/c,/1/a,/b/β
```

The depth of the directory are 3, and I want to remove all the directory those  names that are not in the `26 letters (a-z)`. `Remove ./1, ./$, ./β ...` and `/a/1, /b/β, /a/b/2`.

I try combine `find` and `grep` and `parallel (A gnu xargs)`
the `grep` works weird, if i use `grep [a-z]`, it will also contain the strange letter, for example , `a with a circle on the top`.
So , i wirte this:

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 2|grep -v  '\/[a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|K|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z]+/[a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|K|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z]+'|parallel -X -r rm -r
```

But it just removes all the files! The grep output contain the `.` directory and subdirectory like `/p` which I do not want to delete, but I think according to the regex it should not be contain.

Why does that happen? 
And how can I remove those directory?

Comment: At least the pipes are useless, any characters that are inside [] will be accepted.

Comment: It happens because `+` searches for a literal `+` sign. Your directory names don't contain `+`, so `grep -v` lets them all through.

Comment: I think using `\+` would searches for a literal `+` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find` itself can use regex, why not use that:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type d ! -iregex '.*/[a-z]+' -exec rm -r {} \;
```

Notes:

- `-iregex` : case insensitive regex
- `-exec` : executes a command

Comment: This can remove the directory which have number or symbol as name, but still it can't delete those directory that have some strange name like an `a` with a circle above it, and something like that. I can't type it on my keyboard.

Comment: @Ziu : then replace `.*/[a-z]+` with the longer one: `.*/[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]+`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Bash's special globbing features](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob):

```
$ cd -- "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ mkdir a b 1
$ touch 0 '$' β a/c 1/a b/β
$ ls -R .
.:
'$'  0  1  a  b  β

./1:
a

./a:
c

./b:
β
$ shopt -s extglob globstar
$ rm -r **/!([a-z])/
$ ls -R .
.:
a  b

./a:
c

./b:
```

You can use `ls -d` instead of `rm -r` to check which files will be deleted before going through with it.

Comment: Your glob should be `**/!([a-z])/` since OP mentions _directories_. Also, with `mkdir -p β/β`, you'll get some errors, as `β/` will be globbed before `β/β/` and after removing `β/`, `rm` will complain that  `β/β/` doesn't exist. That's why we like to use `find` with `-depth` to properly handle recursive deletes.

Comment: That complaint you can safely ignore (or remove with `-f`), because the target objective is still met. And removing the directory before the content means that the complete command will be *faster* than removing each file recursively first.